# An SQLException was provoked, java.lang.InterruptedException, am I running out of db connections?

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-webflow

So we run a Hibernate, Spring, Spring Webflow stack. From what I've read so far it might also be important to know we use c3p0-0.9.1.2.

Over the last couple of days we've noticed the server suddenly stop. Users cannot log into the website, nothing appears to happen, the browser simply sits loading the page forever. The server logs also simply halt.

When we notice this we shutdown the tomcat instance and all of a sudden quite a few of the following errors get logged;

```
13:05:57.492 [TP-Processor7]   WARN  o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
13:05:57.492 [TP-Processor7]   ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.InterruptedException
```

Any ideas what these mean? Google hasn't been too helpful. Are we leaking db connections somewhere and the pool cannot gain a new session?

We have just put in a couple new Spring Webflow flows and are experiencing a slightly increased amount of website traffic but we haven't seen this behaviour before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect those `InterruptExceptions` come from the actual shutdown of those threads by the container, and simply indicate that those threads are existant when Tomcat shuts down.

Instead, I would grab a [thread dump](http://expertodev.wordpress.com/2009/05/30/how-to-take-java-thread-dump/) from Tomcat when it next freezes. I would also get a DBA to tell you what's happening in the database. From the above I'm guessing you're hung on a database resource, but a thread dump and analysis from a DBA will certainly point you in the right direction.

Here's a [Thread Dump JSP](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/embed-thread-dump-tool-using) as an alternative means of generating thread dumps.